# Webdriver in Ruby, add more test

Tags: ruby, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver in Ruby, and I am using Aptana Studio as my IDE.

For example I have the following test script:
    require "selenium-webdriver"

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title
##TODO
driver.quit
```

Say if I want to come back and add another action on the TODO comment:
    driver.navigate.to "http://google.com/blahblah"

Assume this step is dependent on the above codes, is there a way that I can run just this line of code to see if it works?

Assume the test is growing large in the future, and I don't want to rerun the all test just to test the steps added later are working.

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: I can't get your point

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe what you want is pause everything with a `gets` call, and in the next line require a file? Then you can modify the required file content and type enter to unstuck the process?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I have modified the post and hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a testing project with proper testing framework for this. Please Google ruby + selenium to get more inputs.

For example, put `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` in test initialize, then all contents in different tests. With such a setup, you can select whichever test you want to test.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

module Test
    class GoogleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
        def setup
            @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
        end

        def teardown
            @driver.quit
        end

        def test_something
            @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

            element = @driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
            element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
            element.submit

            puts @driver.title
        end

        def test_something_else
            @driver.navigate.to "http://google.com/blahblah"

            # do some stuff
        end
    end
end
```